# Override koa-body Type Definition

Tags: typescript, koa

How can I override `koa-body` type definition? `koa-body` has a typing definition like so:

```
declare module "koa" {
    interface Request {
        body: any;
    }
    interface Context {
        body: any;
    }
}
```

I want to override into something like this (file `index.d.ts`):

```
import { Files } from 'formidable'

interface IBody {
  files: Files
}

declare module "koa" {
  interface Request {
    body: IBody
  }

  interface Context {
    body: IBody
  }
}
```

But the intellisense doesn't work, it still show that `ctx.request.body` is `any`. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you need override it? Do you have problem to upload file on server side?

Comment: No. I want a better typing experience.